# setParent works, but without minExpanding

Tags: pyqt, maya, setparent

I'm a 3D technical artist, using `pyqt` in `Maya`, a bit of a novice with `pyqt`.

I have 2 `pyqt` UI files created in Designer, and I load them into `Maya` with `uic.loadUiType()`

I want to assign the 2nd UI file as a child of a tab in the first UI.  I do that with `.setParent()`.

It works fine, except that it doesn't seem to be using the `minExpanding` to expand within the tab, instead it just acts as if its a fixed size, though I have set `minExpanding` on both the tab widget and the widget that I'm setting as its child.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

That size policy applies to how it will behave when contained within a layout, so add a layout to the parent and then call `addWidget()` and pass in the child widget.